# Filtered typed facility factory registration

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I'm currently registering each Typed Facility Factory in its own statement like so

```
_container.Register(Component.For<IDataSourcePickerViewModelFactory>().AsFactory());
_container.Register(Component.For<IDataSourcePickerFactory>().AsFactory());
_container.Register(Component.For<ISetSaveAsFactory>().AsFactory());
_container.Register(Component.For<ISetSaveAsViewModelFactory>().AsFactory());
```

Is there a way to do this based on namespace? Something along the lines of (pseudocode)

```
_container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
    .InNamespace("MyProject.View")
    .Where(x => x.InterfaceName.EndsWith("Factory"))
    .AsFactory());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (var container = new WindsorContainer())
{
    container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

    container.Register(
        Component.For<IBoo>().ImplementedBy<Boo>().LifestyleTransient(),
        Component.For<IBar>().ImplementedBy<Bar>().LifestyleTransient(),

        Types.FromThisAssembly()
            .Where(c => c.Namespace == "MyFactories" && c.Name.EndsWith("Factory"))
            .Configure(c=>c.AsFactory())
        );

    var booFactory = container.Resolve<IBooFactory>();
    var boo = booFactory.Create();
    Console.WriteLine(boo.GetType().FullName);
    booFactory.FreeUp(boo);

    var barFactory = container.Resolve<IBarFactory>();
    var bar = barFactory.Create();
    Console.WriteLine(bar.GetType().FullName);
    barFactory.FreeUp(bar);
}   


namespace MyFactories
{
    public interface IBooFactory
    {
        IBoo Create();
        void FreeUp(IBoo cmp);
    }

    public interface IBarFactory
    {
        IBar Create();
        void FreeUp(IBar cmp);
    }

    public interface IBar{}

    public interface IBoo{}

    public class Boo : IBoo{}

    public class Bar : IBar{}

}
```